# Calculation mistakes of SparseLU in Eigen (C++)

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, eigen

Recently I found that in some certain circumstances, the SparseLU solver will get the wrong answer.

I give an example in the attachment, where "A.csv" is the coefficient matrix of the equation Ax=b, and "b.csv" is the right part of the equation.

The codes are like this:

```
// solve the linear system: Ax = b
Eigen::VectorXd sparselu_x, pardisolu_x;
SparseLU<spmat> solver_splu;
PardisoLU<spmat> solver_pdslu;

// SparseLU results
solver_splu.compute(A);
sparselu_x = solver_splu.solve(b);

// PardisoLU results
solver_pdslu.compute(A);
pardisolu_x = solver_pdslu.solve(b);


// print some of the difference
cout << "sparselu results - pardisolu results (last 5 items):\n\n" << (sparselu_x - pardisolu_x).tail(5) << endl;

cout << "\n\n\n\nA*x - b (sparselu results, last 5 items):\n\n" << (A * sparselu_x - b).tail(5) << endl;
cout << "\n\n\n\nA*x - b (pardisolu results, last 5 items):\n\n" << (A * pardisolu_x - b).tail(5) << endl;
```

And the output:

```
sparselu results - pardisolu results (last 5 items):

 6.25516e-10
 6.36814e-08
-1.45986e-05
  -0.0170633
   -0.437249




A*x - b (sparselu results, last 5 items):

           0
 1.81899e-12
-1.81899e-12
     18.0459
     621.588




A*x - b (pardisolu results, last 5 items):

1.81899e-12
          0
          0
          0
          0
```

Full data and codes about reading the csv file and solving the system are uploaded at:

https://github.com/cpc-tyym/SparseLU-eg

Because of the efficency, I really prefer the sparselu solver, but this mistake makes me choose the pardiso solver, which is 3 times slower than the sparselu solver. So could anyone find out whether the sparselu solver is wrong in somewhere, or did I make any mistakes when solving the equation?

Comment: This sounds serious. Have you found out anything? I'm afraid I can't help you but would be interested as well.

Comment: @Eike Actually I've used the pardiso package due to this problem... Don't know how to contact with the eigen team :(

Comment: I see, a pity. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: While trying to find out whether I can call solve on the same SparseLU solver in parallel I noticed that the `solve` method never changes `m_info` (luckily, I guess I can call in in multiple threads). But then I thought of this. Could your matrix be badly conditioned and SparseLU run into numerical issues which it itself cannot detect?

Comment: I guess you could try SparseQR to find out more.